# Optimising views that utilise functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index, view

One of our developers created a view whereby one of the select columns was wrapped in an RTRIM function. That same column on the underlying table has a non-clustered index on it.

Now queries using this view and a where statement on this column are failing to use the index due to the RTRIM. I need the view's output to be consistent as unfortunately this developer is no longer with us and I can't read his code.

What are some options for optimisation? I've got one, but I'm hoping there is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new computed column on the underlying table that is an RTRIM of the column in question. Add an index on this column. Adjust the view to use this computed column.

Comment: Or make it an [Indexed View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft not used those before. I tried putting a clustered on the view ID column, and a non-clustered on the view column I care about. It didn't help, it still scans the index of the underlying table

Comment: You can try querying with the NOEXPAND hint.  But a better solution is probably to ensure that no trailing spaces are present in the column and eliminate the RTRIM.  You can ensure that no trailing spaces will be present with either a constraint or a trigger.